# How to check Javascript battery usage

Tags: javascript, batterylevel, battery-saver

This sounds like a very strange question as I have probably phrased it wrong.

How can I check how big of an impact my javascript code is having on the battery of a device such as a laptop? I know the website I'm using the JS in is causing my power to drain rapidly through checking Mac Activity monitor and the sound of the fans coming on full speed when the site is on for a while. When I close the tab, everything calms down.

Thanks.

Comment: You sure it's the javascript (directly, at least)? Maybe it's hitting the network a lot.

Comment: It is not javascript, it is you program that uses a lot of CPU operations... You may calculate wasting time for specific operations and figure out where you make CPU working very hard...

Comment: Ok. Well it's technically Chrome, but its an extension I'm working on. Whenever the tab is open the browser starts using a lot more energy in the activity monitor.